# solidworks 2018 part geometry changes on scaling

Tags: solidworks

See the follow file for details:  https://www.filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=757744643cd3d3972ae382af4a4deb91 .  I create a spiral structure which is smooth and beautiful, then scale it up by a factor of 10.  Once it's scaled up, the geometry has changed. Can anybody tell me why, and if there is a way of avoiding it?  Thanks!

[image: operations]
[image: original_geometry]
[image: changed geometry]
edit:  [image: scale dialogue]

Comment: This looks like a bug to me... Certainly not the behaviour I'd expect. Can you include a screenshot of the Scale dialog, and maybe attach the file so I can try scaling it in my 2018 install, and also in 2019?

Comment: scale dialogue added.  note it's around the centroid, if I make it from the origin, the final object doesn't fit within the modeler limits (1000m).  the original file has already been provided :-)

Comment: (in the first line of text of the  question) :-)

Comment: Nope - click the link, it takes you to the image again...

Comment: Looks like you have multiple bodies that are all scaling about their respective centroids? Can you merge them? Or why not make a reference point in the middle of the structure (since origin causes you trouble), and scale from that?

Comment: excellent questions.  file fixed :-)

Comment: ok, first results:  scaling around the centroid after combining works!  -the computer just takes a long time to do the operations, but this might be the same computational intensity as other approaches.  I speculate that if I can introduce a weave so that the different spirals never touch, it might go -much- faster..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108294/discussion-between-juggler-and-jonathan-r-swift).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below. As I said in my comment - the problem that you're having is that each body scales about its *own* centroid. If the origin is not OK for you, then you will need to add another coordinate system.

See the .gif below showing how to do this.

[image]

Comment: accepting this answer on the word of john that it represents the  answer he already gave, in the comments, which worked.  he's awesome. :-D   -as for -why- scaling on the centroid causes the problem.. I haven't the foggiest.   it makes no sense to me. :-S ;-)

Comment: @juggler scaling many things from many different positions isnt the same thing as scaling all from same point.

Comment: @joojaa -you're right, but if  you look at the pictures of the effect being produced, you will agree with me, I hope, that there is  no way that such  a simple explanation could explain the effect I'm seeing.  the parts of my thing are just rotated around an axis, so the centroids could at most be tracing a circle..   ...ahhh... I begin to see how the effect might originate..

Comment: @juggler Object centroids for an object like this are hard to predict form the image and their compound action too. To me the effect is perfectly plausible, but then i am into studying emergent behaviors, that literally make surprising outcomes form simple rules that can not be predicted by humans. So I might be biased to the result.

Comment: @joojaa fascinating!  ..at some point we'll have to get together for a (root)beer with a solidworks programmer and work it all out! ;-)

Comment: @joojaa  ..you lost me..

Comment: @juggler wron thread sorry